# Module object in callable in python - Atom.io as as Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, random, module

```
import random

for i in random(10):
    x = random.random()
    print(x)
```

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run this program in the atom.io

Comment: ```  
`from random import random`

`for i in random(10):`
   ` x = random.random()`
    `print(x) `
 ```

TypeError: random() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: ```    ```  
    `from random import random`

    `for i in random(10):`
       ` x = random.random()`
        `print(x) `
          ```

      TypeError: random() takes no arguments (1 given)